# Overriding elements in a Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of 30 values and am looking to append those values into an empty array.

I created an empty numpy array and used `np.append()` to try and add my values into this empty array.

```
oldArray = np.empty(30)
diameter = np.sqrt(values)
newArray = np.append(oldArray, [diameter])
```

I was hoping that by doing this it would update the old array and give the correct output. However, when I print out `newArray` it simply gives me the values stored in `oldArray`. Any suggestions on how to actually perform this operation?

Comment: can you post a full code?

Comment: This comes up often.  `np.append` should be banished to oblivion.  If you want to create an object iteratively, use the list append.  Don't try to imitate it in numpy arrays.

Comment: For one thing you did not create an empty array, at least not anything like a list `[]`.  `np.empty(30)` is an array of 30 undetermined values.  For another, `np.append` returns a new array, not a modification of the original.  At least you didn't assume it acted in place!  `np.append` is just a poorly named cover for `np.concatenate`.  It is slower than list append, and hard to get right.

Comment: `newArray = np.sqrt(values)`.  No need to append or override values in another array.

Answer (score 0):

for the sake of simplicity, i used np.zeros instead of np.empty because it assign random values to the array, also i assign values ones array.

```
import numpy as np

values = np.ones(30)
oldArray = np.zeros(30)
diameter = np.sqrt(values)
newArray = np.append(oldArray, [diameter])

print('oldArray= ', oldArray)
print(30*'-')
print('newArray= ', newArray)
```

output:

```
oldArray=  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
------------------------------
newArray=  [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.
 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't simulate your problem if I used values as integers, or an array, it always attaches the diameter array to the end as it should. However, considering you are new and you are using an empty array, I think you might be trying to write the values into this array instead.

This is:

```
values = 1
oldArray = np.empty(3)
oldArray[:] = np.sqrt(values)
```

This gives the oldArray filled with the values you require, mind you it wouldn't be the old array this would now be the filled new array:

```
[1. 1. 1.]
```

Perhaps you also want to add individual components in which case

```
values = [1, 2]
oldArray = np.empty(3)
oldArray[0: len(values)] = np.sqrt(values)
```

Would give just the two values changed

```
[1. 1.41421 0.]
```

Below is what I tried to simulate your problem.

```
oldArray = np.empty(3)
print(f"oldArray:{oldArray}, shape:{oldArray.shape}")
values = np.ones(5)
diameter = np.sqrt(values)
newArray = np.append(oldArray, diameter)
print(f"newArray:{newArray}, shape:{newArray.shape}")
```

which output as it should:

```
oldArray:[2.59338625e+161 6.91119945e+212 5.98157061e-154], shape:(3,)
newArray:[2.59338625e+161 6.91119945e+212 5.98157061e-154 1.00000000e+000
1.00000000e+000 1.00000000e+000 1.00000000e+000 1.00000000e+000], shape:(8,)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [23]: values = np.arange(4)
```

If I generate a new set of values, I can just assign it to a variable:

```
In [24]: arr = np.sqrt(values)                                                  
In [25]: arr                                                                    
Out[25]: array([0.        , 1.        , 1.41421356, 1.73205081])
```

I could assign new values to the array, but why?

```
In [26]: arr[:] = [100,200,300,400]                                             
In [27]: arr                                                                    
Out[27]: array([100., 200., 300., 400.])
```

`concatenate` lets me join several arrays - a whole list of them in fact:

```
In [28]: np.concatenate([arr,arr])                                              
Out[28]: array([100., 200., 300., 400., 100., 200., 300., 400.])
```

No need to imitate list append with poorly named `np.append`.  If I must use iteration (with a function that only works with scalars), list append is best:

```
In [29]: alist = []                                                             
In [30]: for v in values: 
    ...:     alist.append(v**.5) 
    ...: alist                                                                  
Out[30]: [0.0, 1.0, 1.4142135623730951, 1.7320508075688772]
In [31]: np.array(alist)                                                        
Out[31]: array([0.        , 1.        , 1.41421356, 1.73205081])
In [32]: np.array([v**.5 for v in values])                                      
Out[32]: array([0.        , 1.        , 1.41421356, 1.73205081])
```